# Running error, [h264 @ 0x10af4a0] AVC: nal size [big number]

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libavformat

I am using libavformat apis to get video frame from a MP4 video file. My code (c++) runs good in my personal computer, but when I try to deploy it into computing server, there are something strange happens. In the function 'av_read_frame()', some errors appear.

```
[h264 @ 0x10af4a0] AVC: nal size 555453589
[h264 @ 0x10af4a0] AVC: nal size 555453589
[h264 @ 0x10af4a0] no frame!
```

My code is like this:

```
if (av_read_frame(_p_format_ctx, &_packet) < 0) {
    return false; 
}
```

But when this error occurs, the program doesn't exit. But the final results are wrong.

The OS of computing server is Linux, the kernel is 2.6.32.
The version of FFmpeg is 3.2.4.
The version of gcc is 4.8.2.

Comment: Can you provide the input file that triggers this behaviour? Judging from the output of libav if you are parsing a file not feeding the frames to it yourself the problem is most likely in the file.

Comment: did you solve your problem? Can you let me know what was the solution?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't solve this problem.